# Net Use in Python 3

Tags: python, windows, perl

anyone could help me with python trying to use NET use, I don't know the diferences between / in python and perl, because code in perl works

```
$runMap = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\net.exe use \\\\$ip\\D\$ /persistent:no /user:$user_name $passwd"; 
system($runMap);
```

But in Python 3 don't work

```
os.system("C:/Windows/System32/net.exe use Z: \\\\ip/D:/ /persistent:no /user:user pass")
```

Comment: 1. [Use raw strings.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l) 2. `C:/Windows/System32/net.exe` aren't those backslashes supposed to go in the other direction?

Comment: first understand what you're doing before attempting to run an exe. I would recommend doing os.system("cd") (if windows) os.system("pwd") (if linux). Then you'll understand where you are

Comment: You are clearly running different commands, so why do you expect same results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl is using *interpolation*, that is, it is possible to embed variables inside a double quoted string, since Perl 5 interpolated variables start with a `$` or a `@` marker.  In your case you are embedding `$user_name` and `$passwd`.

Python variable names are not prefixed by a "magic character" (*sigil*), so you cannot embed them inside strings except by using formatting statements.  There are a couple of regimes, here is one which is a similar idea to `printf`:

```
cmd = "C:/Windows/System32/net.exe use Z: \\\\ip/D:/ /persistent:no /user:%s %s" % (username, passwd)

os.system(cmd)
```

As an ex-Perlmonger I missed interpolation so much I wrote a Python module to support it.  While I learnt a lot about Python doing it, it was otherwise a waste of time.  Python programming is a different style, you don't *need* interpolation any more.

By the way, unlike Perl's `system()`, Python's `os.system()` will *always* spawn a shell (as does C's).  Therefore it is generally considered to be deprecated.  The `subprocess.Popen()` method gives much more control.

EDIT:

With the advent of Python 3.6 and *Literal String Interpolation* (specified in PEP 498) - more commonly known as **f-strings** - my original post needs another way to do it.

Single or double quotes may be used, even triple quotes.  Basically we just put the Python expression, commonly a variable, inside braces (similar to Ruby).

So, for example:

```
os.system(f"C:/Windows/System32/net.exe use Z: \\\\ip/D:/ /persistent:no /user:{username} {passwd}")
```

The comment about `subprocess.Popen()` is also out of date, since Python 3.5 the preferred interface is now `subprocess.run()`.

Comment: `pass` is a reserved keyword in Python. Also, `\\ip/D:/` is an invalid UNC path. I think the OP wants `\\ip\D$`. Also, drive `Z:` may be assigned already, so I'd pass `*` to let the net command assign the drive letter, and then search the output for the assigned drive letter. For example: `net_path = r'%s\System32\net.exe' % os.environ['SystemRoot'];` `unc_path = r'\\ip\D$';` `cmd = '%s use * %s /persistent:no /user:%s %s' % (net_path, unc_path, user, password);` `output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines=True);` `drive = re.findall('\s([A-Z]:)\s', output)[0]`.

Comment: @eryksun:  oops, I missed the `pass`.

Comment: Also the UNC path is invalid and not the same as the Perl code, so the command fails. The OP wants the `D$` 'hidden' share for drive D:.

Comment: Also the OP shouldn't assume that Windows is installed to `C:\Windows`.

Comment: Thanks  I try use your example but invalid password msg with net use and password is correct, maybe the error occurs because have special characters, like #@... in passwd.